# ¿Cómo obtener datos de un listbox en un textbox en c#?

Tags: c#

Tengo un `listbox` y quiero que al seleccionar un item me lo muestre en el `textbox`.

Tengo el siguiente código:

```
public UsuarioAdmin(Usuario u)
{
    InitializeComponent();

    listUsuarios.Items.Add(u.Nombre);
    txtNombre.Text = listUsuarios.SelectedItem.ToString();    
}
```

Pero eso me arroja una `exception`. El IDE me dice que tengo que verificar si el objeto es diferente de `null`.

Básicamente en el formulario tengo un `listbox` y `textbox` y quiero que al seleccionar un item del `listbox` se muestre en el `textbox` para luego ser editado.

Comment: Como pones que es sobre C# en el título he quitado el resto de etiquetas.

Aparte, uff faltan muchos datos, deberías poner mas código para ver si nos aclaramos.

Answer (score 2):

Buen día, primero que todo, aunque se hayan inicializado los componentes (como pones en tu código), el problema es que por defecto no hay ningún item seleccionado, hasta que el usuario seleccione alguno o el programador desde el código asigne alguno. Lo que puedes hacer al iniciar tu programa es revisar sí existen items y seleccionar por defecto alguno.

```
if (listUsuarios.Items.Count)
   listUsuarios.SelectedIndex = 0;
```

Ahora bien, para que se asigne al `TextBox`, lo ideal es que utilices un evento, como el `SelectedIndexChanged`

```
private void listUsuarios_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   txtNombre.Text = listUsuarios.SelectedItem.ToString();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

La variable Nombre de la estructura u (Usuario), podría no haber sido inicializada o no contener ningún valor propio, por lo que el compilador puede generar esa excepción.

Como los datos añadidos a la ListBox proceden del valor u.Nombre, esta ha de ser diferente de null para continuar con la ejecución del código y acceder a su valor.

Condicionando la ejecución a que esa variable no valga null, puedes evitar en parte la falla.

Luego se ha de comprobar que hay un elemento seleccionado en la ListBox (por lo cual habrá al menos 1 Item) para poder asignar su valor al TextBox.

> public UsuarioAdmin(Usuario u)
>
> ```
> {
> InitializeComponent();
>
> if (u.Nombre != null)
>    listUsuarios.Items.Add(u.Nombre);
>
> if (listUsuarios.SelectedItem != null)    
>    txtNombre.Text = listUsuarios.SelectedItem.ToString();     
> }
> ```

Para añadir elementos a la ListBox habrá de contar con otras posibilidades en el conjunto del programa.

Sería más conveniente que el código que agrega elementos al listBox se asocie a un boton o evento, y que la asignación del elemento seleccionado se asocie también adecuadamente, activando por ejemplo el evento **ListBox.SelectionChanged** o algún botón y / o condicional ( if ) al efecto.

*De modo que se puedan añadir varios elementos, y se asigne la selección al TextBox con una mejor interacción, más funcional.*

Answer (score 0):

Cuando escribes en el constructor de una clase, esta clase solo se instancia cuando la defines.

En tu caso, solo tienes un parametro en el constructor, pero eso no quiere decir que el `ListBox` se vaya a inicializar seleccionando el primer valor por defecto, cuando en su efecto ni si quiera se ha mostrado en pantalla.

La línea que tiene problemas en este código es esta:

```
txtNombre.Text = listUsuarios.SelectedItem.ToString();
```

Asumiré que tu error se trata con `listUsuarios`, si agregas un nuevo elemento a una lista cuyo primer elemento no se ha seleccionado, la propiedad `SelectedItem` será igual a `null`, por lo que deberías cambiar esa línea a:

```
txtNombre.Text = listUsuarios.Items[0].ToString();
```

Dado que en el constructor solo agregas un nombre de usuario y por ende, el `listUsuarios` terminará teniendo un solo elemento.

Espero te haya ayudado.

Answer (score 0):

Hola estimado para ello primero deberías asegurarte de llenar tu listbox correctamente, y luego debes programar en el evento de selección del listbox, te daré un ejemplo, voy a llenar el listbox en el evento Load de mi formulario con elementos cualquiera, en este caso bebidas gaseosas, y luego al seleccionar un item de listbox el textbox se llenará con elemento seleccionado para como mencionas luego puedas editarlo:

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)//Evento load del formulario(Se ejecuta cuando se inicia el formulario)
        {
            //Agregamos Items a nuestro Listbox
            listBox1.Items.Add("Coca Cola");
            listBox1.Items.Add("Pepsi");
            listBox1.Items.Add("Guaraná");
            listBox1.Items.Add("Inca Kola");
        }

        private void listBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e) //Evento del listbox para seleccionar un ítem
        {
            txtEditar.Text = listBox1.SelectedItem.ToString(); //Asignamos el ítem seleccionado al textbox
        }
```

Eso sería todo, con eso cada vez que selecciones un elemento del listbox se llenará el Textbox.

Answer (score 0):

Dentro del método UsuarioAdmin() has puesto InitializeComponent();

Eso inicializa la ventana y todos sus componentes, y básicamente se ejecuta necesariamente, justo antes de poder usar las ventanas y controles de los WinForms y demás.

Creo que eso no debería ir ahí, sino que debes dejarlo allí donde se úbica por defecto, al crear un proyecto WinForm al uso, salvo que sepas perfectamente el motivo por el que reubicas eso en otro lado (por ejemplo, linea arriba o linea abajo, de alguna otra cosa, para desarrollar una interfaz gráfica)

No es un Control.Refresh(), ni un Form.Refresh();
Se trata de un IntializeComponent();

Que a parte, si o si, debe haber sido llamado, antes de ejecutar Form1_Load();

De otro modo probablemente, pueda inicilizar a destiempo o tarde, (por no estar es antes de Form1_Load()) los objetos de ventanas y controles del proyecto, e interfiera generando una falla, con la disposición de los controles, tales como el ComboBox y el TextBox que tratas de utilizar.

[What does InitializeComponent() do, and how does it work in WPF https://stackoverflow.com/questions ..](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/245825/what-does-initializecomponent-do-and-how-does-it-work-in-wpf)